# when clicking any option from menu list, the target of executing the url is inside another div tag in the same html file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a side nav with dynamic menu list coming from db.
When I click an option in menulist, It should refresh inside another div tag "content" and display the rendered page of that related menu list option inside that tag.

To simplify, The div tag should work as dynamic iframe pulling the options href file and displaying inside it.

This is my menu code written in PHP

```
<?php
require 'dbh.inc.php';
function show_menu(){
    global $conn;
    $menus = "";
    $menus .= gmm($conn);
    return $menus;
}
function gmm( $conn, $parent_id=NULL){
    $menu = "";
    $sql = "";
    $row="";
    if(is_null($parent_id) ) {
         $sql="select * from `kitting` where `parent_id` is null";
    }
    else{
        $sql="select * from `kitting` where `parent_id`='$parent_id'";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if( $row['page']){
            $menu .='<li><p><span class="subtitle is-6 has-text-dark has-text-weight-semibold is-uppercase"><a href=./'.$row['page'].'>'.$row['title'].'</a></span></p></li>';
        }
        else{
            $menu .='<li><p><span class="subtitle is-6 has-text-dark has-text-weight-semibold is-uppercase"></span><a href="#">'.$row['title'].'</a></p></li>';
        }
        $menu .= '<ul class="menu-list">'.gmm($conn, $row['id']).'</ul>';
        $menu .= '';
     }
     return $menu;
    }


  ?>
```

It has to show the html page rendered data inside  below tag and  when I click another menu, the div tag has to refresh with new data.

```
<div class="content">
data comes here dynamically
<div>
```

Kindly help as I checked many websites and unable to find anything related.

Comment: you need to use jquery `toggle();` hide/show to do that I thing

Comment: Can you elobrate?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using templates? If the file names for your templates match the dynamic values for each $row['page'] you can change the href to a dynamic URL like.

`myScript.php?parent_id=<parent_id>&template=$row['page']`

`$template = isset($_GET['template']) ? $_GET['template'] : '';`

Then, within your content tags include the path to the matching template.

`include('/templates/'.$template.'.php');`

Comment: Hi Catie, Thanks for answering the question. Can you please elaborate more? What do you mean by template?      Where to include this script ? " myScript.php?parent_id=<parent_id>&template=$row['page']     $template = isset($_GET['template']) ? $_GET['template'] : '';"    The dynamic values and page names are matching

Answer (score 1):

A basic example to give you an idea you beter search for Multi-level Vertical Side Navbars there are tons of them arround.

```js
$(function () {
     $("#YourDivID").click(function() {
       $("ul").slideToggle();
       $("ul ul").css("display", "none");
     });
     $("ul li").click(function(e) {
       $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
       $(this).find("ul ul").css("display", "none");
       e.stopPropagation();
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="YourDivID">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Click on me
    <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

You need css to hide on default, as a helper for jquery

Jquery will Hide/Show oclick
Click on dropdown to see how it works

Comment: Thanks for helping out.  The Menu is working fine with php script. My question is when ever I click the menu, the url  goes to other page and display but I wanted to show in the same page's div tag named "content"  means it only refresh content div tag and bring that particular page and show up in that div tag. Can you help me with that ? I have checked many websites but unable to find related.

Comment: Well this is your question **I have a side menu with dynamic menus coming from db displayed. When I click, It has to show the file inside a div tag called 'content'.** and my answer does what you asked in question, **You will be redirected to the page you linked, when you click on an url, you got to remove url to make menu works** And answer of your comment you can link to menues like so : `<a href=./page/menu/1.'>'.$row['title'].'</a><a href=./page/menu/2.'>'.$row['title'].'</a>` then it will display the menu you clicked. there isnt another way. Please edit you question clear what you need.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, will check accordingly !